# function to find username from session id

Tags: sql, teradata

To know the username from a session id, I would use the below.

```
sel username from dbc.sessioninfo where sessionno=27778311
```

Is there any other option as well? I am trying to find the answer to the below actually

Which built-in function could be used to determine which login name is assigned to this session?

Answer (score 2):

Here are the Teradata functions that I believe you are searching for to answer the question:

```
SELECT USER; -- Returns current username
SELECT SESSION; -- Returns current session id.
```

**Edit:**
Depending on the version of Teradata, you can use the Open PMPC APIs to obtain this information, in particular you can use the MonitorSession API:

```
SELECT UserName FROM TABLE (MonitorSession(1,'*', 27778311)) AS MyTable;
```

This should work in release 13.x and newer. You can find more about these functions in the *Application Programming Reference* manual.

Comment: Yes I am aware of these, but how can they work with one another that is what I wanted to know. i.e. if I have a session id, can I pass it to the USER function so that it would give me the login name?